# Ubuntu cannot find an SSD drive installed on 21" imac in place of the CDROM

Tags: ssd, refind

I have an iMac with macos installed both on the original drive and on an SSD that I installed in place of the CDROM. Both they are working.
Since I would like to use only ubuntu on this machine in place of macOS, I installed rEFInd and everything is ok, except that I cannot install linux on the SSD partition, and when I install linux on the original drive, the ssd is not present in the drives list.
Any ideas?

Running this command:

```
sudo lsblk -f; sudo lshw -C storage
```

I get this output:

```
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                             
├─sda4 ext4                e30b49ad-4457-4b5f-bf38-a8df7d95a58d /
├─sda2 hfsplus iMacFRA     9f8eb5e2-8db9-3608-846a-79dff9606566 /media/fra/iMacF
├─sda5 swap                2c25d919-353c-48f2-b14c-0a792b57ce13 [SWAP]
├─sda3 hfsplus Recovery HD 0cd7b4a6-22e5-3480-b6a0-f75c62a86ec1 
└─sda1 vfat    EFI         70D6-1701                            /boot/efi
  *-ide                   
       description: IDE interface
       product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: ide bus_master
       configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
       resources: irq:21 ioport:7108(size=8) ioport:711c(size=4) ioport:7100(size=8) ioport:7118(size=4) ioport:70e0(size=16)
  *-storage
       description: SATA controller
       product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:30 ioport:70f8(size=8) ioport:7114(size=4) ioport:70f0(size=8) ioport:7110(size=4) ioport:7020(size=32) memory:d0604000-d06047ff
  *-scsi
       physical id: 2
       logical name: scsi2
       capabilities: emulated
```

Comment: What model year is the iMac? Where did you install rEFInd? Your question states that you had macOS installed on the HDD. Could macOS access the SSD? If so, how? Were you able to format a partition on the SSD and see this partition in the Finder? I am trying to determine if this is a hardware or software  problem.

Comment: Could you please boot the Ubuntu live system on the installation medium (select “Try Ubuntu” in the boot menu), open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `sudo lsblk -f; sudo lshw -C storage` and [edit] your question to include the output of that command sequence? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the iMac is 21" model, later I will specify exactly the model running macos. Yes macOS can access the SSD and macOS is installed in both hard drives. They are mounted regularly as hard drives, and before installing ubuntu I created a partition on each drive (fat32). Yes the disks and partitions are regularly seen on finder.

Comment: @DavidFoerster  thanks, I edited the question, btw, the ubuntu installation program see only the hard drive, the second hard disk is not an option. I would exclude an hardware issue since macOS is installed over the SSD since 2-3 years and I still can boot to macOS from rEFInd . Is it possible the ubuntu doesn't accept a disk installed in place of the cdrom?

Comment: Yes, that's possible – kind of. The problematic part is usually the storage *controller*, i. e. the subsystem inside the computer that interfaces with the storage medium, and not drive itself since the computer would only see it as a generic block device thanks to the storage controller (if it worked). Which release of Ubuntu is this? A more recent one may include a suitable driver for the storage controller responsible for the drive bay.

Comment: I'm a little confused though because both storage controllers here are from Intel's ICH line which tend to have good to excellent driver support.

Comment: 16.04 LTS, last update

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: BTW, I have done exactly like this video, except installing the TRIM support http://www.btobey.com/learn/imac-ssd-install.php